# How to increase the height of iframe of container page from the page shown inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an application which will be shown inside an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/xxxxx.aspx"></iframe>
```

The height and width of this container is  `900px and 600px`.
I want my app to be in full screen, 
so now is it possible to change the height and width of the container iframe??
P.S The iframe is not in same project, so

```
$("iframe").css("height","1000px")
```

won't work as its a different file.

Comment: iframe can take height and width of its parent, to the max.. so if u have parent as `height:700px` and `width:400px`, iframe will get set inside it. if its height and width is greater den parent den it will be overflown inside the parent. So if you are not setting iframe inside any container then you can set it to fullscreen and the page inside it will also be visible as fullscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the context in which the selector should be applied:

```
 $("iframe", window.parent.document).css("height","1000px");
```

Here is an example with different files: http://www.css-arts.com/iframe_test/iframe_test.html

Browsers usually blocks the access to the iframes parent when the iframe content page is another domain than the parent page. If this is the case you have no chance.

Comment: This will not work if the iframe is hosted on a different domain, will it?

Comment: The browser and its js engine will not care about the domain, I think.

Comment: In general it works that way. I used it successfully to show and hide a div tag containing an iframe by calling `$("#MyDivId", window.parent.document).show();` or `.hide();` from inside the iframe. Unfortunately it is difficult to set up a fiddle for your case. Did you have a look at the source code of the parent page?

Comment: it worked when the two html files are not same?? 
I mean when one html file has an iframe inside which another html file is shown???

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will try to set up an example.

Comment: Thanks Rob, my app will be in different domain i guess !! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
<iframe src="http://adobe.com" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="600px" width="900px"></iframe>
```